# Enforce a password complexity policy on login?

Tags: security, ldap

I am using LDAP and PAM modules.
I know it is possible to enforce user password complexity when changing user password, by using pam_cracklib.so in common-password file.

What interests me - is it possible to enforce password complexity checking on user login (ssh) by same pam_cracklib.so or similar ?

The reason is - I cannot control external AD side but can change configuration in PC.

Expected behavior - if user has password bellow set complexity level he cannot login at all.